# Добавить динамически созданный html на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Чёт не могу раздуплить кусочек кода, из json приходит ответ сервера, создаю таблицу динамически и добавляю на страницу, в результате вижу `[object Object]`, а не созданный html.

Цель - создать несколько инпутов с разными value, затем обернуть дивом, создать так несколько строк и вывести на страницу.

Код:

```
    var _html = '',
    _s = '<input type="text" value="" name="">';

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

    var _row = '';
    _row += $(_s).attr('value', response[i].nid);

    // _row += $(_s).attr('value', response[i].oid);
    // _row += $(_s).attr('value', response[i].town);

    $(_row).wrap('<div class="line"></div>');
    _html += _row;
}
$('#res').html(_html);
```

Если `_row = $(_s).attr('value', response[i].nid);` без знака плюс, то хтмл выводится, если `+=` - бяка.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь строку сложить с объектом _html += _row;

Comment: @VladimirMorulus и что тут во что надо преобразовать?

Comment: Надо изучать javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как и было сказано в комментариях, вы складываете к переменной `_html`, которая содержит в себе строку, переменную `_row` который является `jQuery` объектом. Соотвественно, из-за не совпадения типов у объекта вызывается метод `.toString()` который и возращает вам строчку  `[object Object]`.

В Вашем примере надо работать либо с строчками либо с объектами. Лучше всего с объектами работать.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/2wq3fd50/).

```js
var _html = '',
  _s = '<input type="text" value="" name="">',
  response = [{
    nid: 1
  }, {
    nid: 2
  }];
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

  var _row = $(_s).attr('value', response[i].nid);
  var div = $('<div class="line"></div>');
  div.append(_row);
  $('#res').append(div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res">

</div>
```

Comment: да, именно так и требовалось, призабыл про данную возможность.

Answer (score 3):

Если посмотреть в справку по [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) можно увидеть, что если эта функция используется как сеттер, то возвращаемое значение - jQuery object.

Таким образом в строка

```
_row += $(_s).attr('value', response[i].nid)
```

равносильна

```
""+{}
```

которая приводит к преобразованию объекта в строку, а по умолчанию для объектов выводится

```
[object Object]
```

Кроме этого есть еще одна, не очевидная ошибка. Метод `wrap` - работает только с элементами которые уже являются вложенными куда-либо. Поэтому вместо него лучше использовать `append`, или `appendTo`

Ну и для работы с массивами можно использовать `map`, `reduce` и т.д.

Например:

```js
var _line = '<div class="line"></div>',
  _s = '<input type="text" value="" name="">';

var response = [{
  nid: 10,
  oid: 11,
  town: 'twn'
}, {
  nid: 110,
  oid: 111,
  town: '1twn'
}];

$('#res').append(
  response.map(function(el) {
    return Object.keys(el).reduce(function(row, key) {
      return row.append(
        $(_s).attr('value', el[key])
      );
    }, $(_line));
  })
);
```

```css
.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Один из вариантов решения вопроса в комментарии

```js
var _line = '<div class="line"></div>',
  _s = '<input type="text" value="" name="">';

var response = [{
  nid: 10,
  oid: 11,
  town: 'twn'
}, {
  nid: 110,
  oid: 111,
  town: '1twn'
}];

$('#res').append(
  response.map(function(el) {
    return Object.keys(el).reduce(function(row, key) {
      return row.append(
        $(_s).attr('value', el[key]).addClass(key)
      );
    }, $(_line)).find('.oid').after($('<a href="url">Link</a>')).end();
  })
);
```

```css
.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Если после инпута oid еще добавить ссылку `<a>ссылка</a>`, которой нет в входящем массиве, как лучше поступить? Очевидное - `if( key ==  ) { return row.append() } else ( return row.append (ссылка))`

Comment: @Jean-Claude, добавил еще пример в ответ. Но все зависит от конечной разметки, и какие варианты вообще могут быть, то есть что именно и куда может потребоваться вставить

Comment: набросал так http://jsbin.com/hudujupete/edit?js,output ясно, в дополнении как раз подобное.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, обновил ответ

Comment: окок, пасиб....